# pandas pivot table aggfunc troubleshooting

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

This `DataFrame` has two columns, both are object type.

```
  Dependents Married
0          0      No
1          1     Yes
2          0     Yes
3          0     Yes
4          0      No
```

I want to aggregate 'Dependents' based on 'Married'.

```
table = df.pivot_table(
        values='Dependents',
        index='Married',
        aggfunc = lambda x: x.map({'0':0,'1':1,'2':2,'3':3}).mean())
```

This works, however, surprisingly, the following doesn't:

```
table = df.pivot_table(values = 'Dependents', 
        index = 'Married', 
        aggfunc = lambda x: x.map(int).mean())
```

It will produce a `None` instead.

Can anyone help explain?

Comment: Looks you're missing a set of parentheses around the lambda in the second set. Also, why not just use aggfunc=int?

Comment: is there a reason you don't convert the whole thing to integers when importing or preprocessing? `df = pd.read_csv('bleh.csv').assign( Dependents = lambda d: d.Dependents.astype("int"))` or ay similar method?

Comment: @Sohier Dane. I don't believe the () is missed around the lambda function. I was trying to map a pd Series if str to int then get a mean value of it. I need know the average dependents that married has vs single.

Comment: @xysmas. yes. convert to int would be simpler. However the data is not clean, the 'Dependents' column has values like '3+', ' 3+ ', and 'NaN', It need some preprocessing before the conversion.  Actually now I think the first method seems cumbersome, but is robust to handle unexpected values other than '1','2','3', and '0'.

Comment: @user2951327 FWIW, I think that if the data is dirty, cleaning it up inside the `aggfunc` of a pivot, is one of the least straightforward ways of going about it. Why not first clean it up, then do the pivot? It's much easier to see what's happening, and also allows you to perform other operations besides pivoting.

Comment: @Ami Tavory: Agree. This is part of the clean up. I am trying to fill the missing values of the dependents column. By pivoting, I try to get the mean # of dependents of married/single family and used for fillna. before this step, i have cleaned up '3+', this step is to clean NaN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both examples of code provided in your question work. However, they are not the idiomatic way to achieve what you want to do -- particularly the first one.

I think this is the proper way to obtain the expected behavior.

```
# Test data
df = DataFrame({'Dependents': ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0'],
                'Married': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No']})

# Converting object to int
df['Dependents'] = df['Dependents'].astype(int)
# Computing the mean by group
df.groupby('Married').mean()

         Dependents
Married            
No             0.00
Yes            0.33
```

However, the following code works.

```
df.pivot_table(values = 'Dependents', index = 'Married', 
               aggfunc = lambda x: x.map(int).mean())
```

It is equivalent (and more readable) of converting to `int` with `map` before pivoting data.

```
df['Dependents'] = df['Dependents'].map(int)
df.pivot_table(values = 'Dependents', index = 'Married')
```

## Edit

I you have messy `DataFrame`, you can use `to_numeric` with the `error` parameter set to `coerce`.

> If `coerce`, then invalid parsing will be set as `NaN`

```
# Test data
df = DataFrame({'Dependents': ['0', '1', '2', '3+', 'NaN'], 
                 'Married': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No']})

df['Dependents'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Dependents'], errors='coerce')
print(df)

   Dependents Married
0         0.0      No
1         1.0     Yes
2         2.0     Yes
3         NaN     Yes
4         NaN      No

print(df.groupby('Married').mean())

         Dependents
Married            
No              0.0
Yes             1.5
```

Comment: yes. I agree it's cleaner. but I don't know why it doesn't work. maybe there is other reason. i am ok to close this issue

Comment: Great, so you can check the answer

Comment: your approach may not work with messy data, for example, with df = DataFrame({'Dependents': ['0', '1', '2', '3+', 'NaN'], 'Married': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No']}), the astype(int) won't work.  to_numeric would translate '3+' to NaN, which is not you want probably, `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.map({'0':0,'1':1,'2':2,'3':3, '3+': 3}) is messy but acceptable.

Comment: @FrankZhu Thanks for the comment (and for the downvote). Please post your best answer and I will be happy to vote up if it works fine.

Comment: see my answer above @Romain

Answer (score 0):

My originally question was why the method 2 using map(int) doesn't work. None of the above answers my question. Therefore there is no best answer.

However, as I look back, I found now in pandas 0.22, method 2 does work. I guess the problem is in pandas.

To robustly do the aggregation, my solution would be

```
df.pivot_table(
        values='Dependents',
        index='Married',
        aggfunc = lambda x: x.map(lambda x:int(x.strip("+"))).mean())
```

To make it cleaner, I guess you could first translate the column "Dependents" to integer then do the aggregation.